# Using openapi-generator for typescript-angular, how to generate just a module inside an existing Angular project instead a full separate package?

Tags: angular, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

I am using [openapi-generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/usage) for [typescript-angular](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-angular).

I can successfully generate an Angular module, with all artifacts, however it is a separate npm package.

I do understand, that this approach has its benefits, and a separate package can be maintained, versioned, distributed etc, in a professional way.

However still, I would like to just generate a new module inside in my existing Angular application. Is there a way to configure the generator to accomplish that task?

In case if not, what manual steps are required to transform and integrate the generated source code to get this result (meaining: a module in my existing Angular application)

Answer (score 3):

If you use this command:

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -i yourApiYAMLfile.yaml -g typescript-angular -o src/app/api
```

or

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -i yourApiSwaggerfile.json -g typescript-angular -o src/app/api
```

to generate your client code as part of your app.

You can then use the models and services generated, directly from your app.

Check this article I wrote out of this: https://blog.josematos.work/use-auto-generated-client-code-to-consume-your-api-from-an-angular-app-363c64f6c83a